# Display link to next FUTURE-DATED post in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to display navigation links on single.php to point to the "previous" and "next" dated posts from within a category. I know how this works, so that's not the issue.

My issue is, Wordpress doesn't seem to want to display my published future-dated posts, even if I stick a query_posts( 'post_status=future,publish' ) before the loop. If I navigate to a future-dated post, it will display a link to the previous post without error. It's navigating into the future that is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that a "scheduled" post is not the same as a "published" post, and since the next_post_link() function will only display the next "published" post, my "scheduled" posts wouldn't be included.

I think I've solved this. Using [The Future Is Now](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/the-future-is-now/) plugin my future-dated posts are automatically set to post_status "published" rather than "scheduled", meaning that they are included in my next_post_link() result.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the [Show Future Posts on Single Post](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/show-future-posts-on-single-post/) plugin to achieve this.  It works on Wordpress 3.

Comment: I am also on WP 3. I've tried using this plugin as well, but still it doesn't seem to permit navigating to future posts via the next_post_link() function.

Comment: OK - I see what you mean now - I've only used it to create linked lists of future pages. I guess adapting the next_post_link() function from link-template.php in the wp-includes folder would be the place to start.  Sorry don't have time to look just now.